# POMA Template: Tex capacity exceeded with line in math mode

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, linguistics, gb4e

I am required to use the POMA template for my paper, originally written in the ACL2017 template(links below). This has lead to some serious breakdowns wrt the bibliography and math mode, that I have not been able to troubleshoot alone. Any insights would be appreciated greatly. The document was built using Sublime’s Basic Builder(Xelatex).

Details:

Here is a link to the template I need to use(scroll to MANUSCRIPT FORMAT): [POMA Template](https://asa.scitation.org/pma/info/policies)

Link to Overleaf: [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/18673147rwddrrwzvggz#/70294499/)

My document header:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letter]{article}
  \usepackage{poma_style}
\usepackage{mathtools} %added this to check if output would change
\usepackage{amsfonts,bm}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\date{\today}
\title{}
```

Document tail:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\expandafter\ifx\csname natexlab\endcsname\relax\def\natexlab#1{#1}\fi

\bibitem[{Boersma and Weenink(2018)}]{Boersma2018}
Paul Boersma and David Weenink. 2018.
\newblock \href{http://www.praat.org/}{Praat: Doing phonetics by computer
  [computer program]}.
\newblock \href{http://www.praat.org/}{http://www.praat.org/}.

    %bib items copies from the .bbl file with the acl template(link below) template used on the latex document, document did not compile when I tried to use a .bib file and a bibliography style.
\end{thebibliography}
```

After a bunch of citation warnings, I got the wanring `Draft.tex:154: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000]. […ion{a\(_1\) and a\(_2\) models - V\(_1\)}]`

Here is the corresponding line: `\subsection{a\(_1\) and a\(_2\) models - V\(_1\)}`

When forced, the PDF did compile till this subsection, with question marks in place of citations.

The same document compiles when I use the [ACL2017 template](http://acl2017.org/calls/papers/) (scroll to paper submission and templates), with the bibliography style ‘acl’.

log file output:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 3891.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 3896.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 3901.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 3906.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 3936.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \emph on input line 3961.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \- on input line 4015.
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/redefine-command"
. 
. Redefining command \oldstylenums with sig. 'm' on line 4110.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \liningnums with sig. 'm' on line 4114.
.................................................
))
\g__fontspec_family_TimesNewRoman_int=\count278
.................................................
. fontspec info: "defining-font"
. 
. Font family 'TimesNewRoman(0)' created for font 'Times New Roman' with
. options [Ligatures=TeX].
.  
.  This font family consists of the following NFSS series/shapes:
.  
. - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"Times New
. Roman/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
. - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
. - 'bold' (bx/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"Times New
. Roman/B/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
. - 'bold small caps'  (bx/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
. - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"Times New
. Roman/I/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
. - 'italic small caps'  (m/itsc) with NFSS spec.: 
. - 'bold italic' (bx/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"Times New
. Roman/BI/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
. - 'bold italic small caps'  (bx/itsc) with NFSS spec.: 
.................................................
LaTeX Info: Redefining \rmfamily on input line 14.    


LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [letter].    

(350bd2823f069ee32f5db725c9674f68/POMA Draft.aux)
\openout1 = `"POMA Draft.aux"'.    

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.    

*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: xetex
* paper: <default>
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(72.26999pt, 469.75502pt, 72.26999pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(72.26999pt, 650.43001pt, 72.26999pt)
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=469.75502pt
* \textheight=650.43001pt
* \oddsidemargin=0.0pt
* \evensidemargin=0.0pt
* \topmargin=-37.0pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=11.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=59.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)    

Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.
.................................................
. fontspec info: "setup-math"
. 
. Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid this).
.................................................
\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup9
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n on input line 1
6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n on input line 
16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n --> TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n on 
input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/it on input line
 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/bx/n on input line
 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n --> TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/bx/n on
 input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/bx/it on input li
ne 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/bx/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/bx/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 27.
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msb on input line 27.    

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)    

LaTeX Warning: Citation `masica1991' on page  undefined on input line 27.    


LaTeX Warning: Citation `masica1991' on page  undefined on input line 31.    


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Ohala1983' on page  undefined on input line 54.    


LaTeX Warning: Citation `passy1890' on page  undefined on input line 55.    


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Ohala1997' on page  undefined on input line 74.    


Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 13.6pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.    

[1    

]    

LaTeX Warning: Citation `Gorman2011' on page  undefined on input line 118.    


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Boersma2018' on page  undefined on input line 118.    

File: iskarous2009.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use iskarous2009.pdf>    

LaTeX Warning: Citation `iskarous2010' on page  undefined on input line 123.    


LaTeX Warning: Citation `iskarous2010' on page  undefined on input line 123.    


LaTeX Warning: Citation `escudero2009' on page  undefined on input line 134.    


LaTeX Warning: Citation `escudero2009' on page  undefined on input line 134.    

! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000].
\gb@ifnextchar #1#2#3->
                       \let \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}\def \reserv...
l.154 ...ion{a\(_1\) and a\(_2\) models - V\(_1\)}

If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.    


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 15697 strings out of 492969
 314528 string characters out of 6133924
 443451 words of memory out of 5000000
 19588 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 539900 words of font info for 69 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 3334i,11n,10002p,631b,443s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
Output written on 350bd2823f069ee32f5db725c9674f68/POMA Draft.pdf (1 page).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error can be reproduced with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}
\subsection{a\(_1\)}
Lorem
\end{document}
```

and occurs because `gb4e` changes the meaning of `_` so that it works outside of math mode (so you can just write `a_1` instead of `a\(_1\)`). These changes, however, do not work well in moving arguments such as section headings.

---

If we are not talking about a mathematical entity here, for which I would strongly suggest `\(a_1\)` or `\(\mathrm{a}_1\)`, you can try

```
a\textsubscript{1}
```

or with `amsmath`/`mathtools`

```
\(\text{a}\sb{1}\)
```

in the section heading.

---

If you never use the fact that `gb4e` lets you use `_` and `^` outside of math mode, you can also add `\noautomath` directly after you load `gb4e`.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are absolutely right about gb4e causing errors.